# Comparing two sets of exponential data T(t)=−e^(−kt)

Tags: probability

I have two sets of exponential data (temperature measurements) of the form:

$T(t)=−e^{(−kt)}$.

$k$ is a constant that determines the rate of temperature change. 1 temperature measurement was taken every 10 seconds to obtain 200 temperature readings for each data set. Under normal circumstances, I could use ANOVA to compare the data and determine its variability and error. This assumes a normal distribution, however, which my exponential data is not. I believe it is of Poisson distribution. What is the best way to compare these two data sets to determine variability? I cannot compare datapoint to datapoint since I can't guarantee that I measured the temperatures starting at the exact same initial point (say set 1 started at $t=0$, set 2 could have started at $t=.01$)

Comment: Why would temperature measurements come from a Poisson distribution? They're not counts.

Comment: @Spacedman The histogram shows something that is poisson-like. It is most definitely not a normal distribution. Further, the equation the best models the temperature measurements is an exponential, and from what I've read, exponential data is poisson distribution.

Comment: What do you want to compare? H0: k1=k2?

Comment: @keiv.fly yes. Whats the appropriate way to do that, and to quantify by how much that statement is/isn't true

Comment: You have a linear regression in logarithms (logT = log(-1)-k*t). You can use this answer for equally of beta in linear regressions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions

Comment: Just because when you plot Y against X that the *curve* looks like a Poisson density function, does not mean that your *response* is a Poisson random variable."exponential data is Poisson distribution" is meaningless.

Comment: You can *only* use the log-transform linear regression method *if* each measurement is independent. You've done two experiments where the measurements are taken as time goes by, and as such there's a strong case for serial correlations between measurements in time - if A(x) is high compared to B(X), then A(x+1) might be a bit high as well, and so you've not got independent measurements which you need for the inference from simple linear regression. You have to have a model for your *errors* as well as your mean response.

Comment: @Spacedman I didn't say that the CURVE looks like poisson, did I? I said that the histogram, aka, not plotting X versus Y, plotting the probability distribution function.

Comment: @spacedman You've really only shot down anything that's been said, without adding any value. the QUESTION is how would YOU approach comparing these two data sets. And if you're confident that the pdf of an equation of the form y=-e^-x is not poisson distribution, then what is it? So far you've offered no suggestions.

Comment: @Spacedman, also your assertion about A(x+1) being a bit high as well is exactly what I'm trying to quantify. The difference will likley be due to two things: 1) measurement error and 2) difference in material properties between the two units I am measuring. Because I chose my measurement instruments carefully to reduce the significance of error introduced, I can assume that any variations are due to #2. So, back to the question at hand -- how to look at the differences?

Comment: The histogram of *what*? If you fit a linear regression model, its the histograms of the *residuals* that should have a Normal distribution, the histogram of the measurements or the responses is a function of the sampling scheme.

Comment: Assume I'm completely lost here and let's get to basics -- what is this distribution of -e^-x?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85101/discussion-between-spacedman-and-montserrat).